# How do I inject the reliability of machines into my ANN

Tags: sql-server, machine-learning, exponential, reliability, weibull

I would like to predict the Reliability of my physical machines by ANN.

**Q1)** What is the right metric that measure the reliability for repairable machine.

**Q2)** In order to calculate the reliability of each machine in each time period or row should I calculate `TBF` or `MTBF`, and feed my `ANN`.

**Q3)** Is `ANN` a good machine learning approach to solve my issue

Lets take a look.

In my predictor `ANN`. One of the input is the current reliability value for my physical machines by applying the right distribution function with right metric MTBF or MTTF. In sample data, there are two machines with some log events.

`Time` , `machine ID`, and `event_type`. `event_type = 0` when a machine became available to the cluster, `event_type=1` machine failed, and when `event_type=2` when a machine available to the cluster had its available resources changed.

For non-repairable product MTTF is preferred to use to measure the reliability, and MTBF is for repairable product.

What is the right metric to get the current reliability value for each time period **row** , is it `TBF or MTBF` . Previously I use `MTTF= TOTAL UPTIME/TOTAL NUMBER OF FAILURE`. To calculate the `UPTIME`, I subtract the `time` in `event_type = 1` from first previous `time` in `event_type=0`, and so on, then divide `the total UPTIME` by `number of failure`. Or I need to `TBF` for each row. `Machine events` table looks like:

```
time              machine_id    event_type  R()
0                    6640223       0    
30382.66466          6640223       1    
30399.2805           6640223       0    
37315.23415          6640223       1    
37321.64514          6640223       0    
0                   3585557842     0    
37067.13354         3585557842     1    
37081.0917          3585557842     0    
37081.2932          3585557842     2    
37321.33633         3585557842     2    
37645.77424         3585557842     1    
37824.73506         3585557842     0    
37824.73506         3585557842     2    
41666.42118         3585557842     2
```

After Preprocessing previous table of `machine events` to get `input_2 (Reliability)` to the training data table the expected table should be look like:

```
start_time  machine_id  input_x1    input_2_(Relibility)    Predicied_output_Relibility
0                111    0.06         xx.xx  
1                111    0.04         xx.xx  
2                111    0.06         xx.xx  
3                111    0.55         xx.xx  
0                222    0.06         xx.xx  
1                222    0.06         xx.xx  
2                222    0.86         xx.xx  
3                222    0.06         xx.xx
```

Comment: possible dupe of [What is the system's mean time to failure?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/what-is-the-systems-mean-time-to-failure)

Comment: Thanks @underscore_d, in your example, the MTTF is given. Here in my post, I want to find the MTTF.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: SQL SERVER, SQL

Comment: always add the database type into the question tags please, not a comment

Comment: @user3172906, you might provide some help

Comment: You have changed the question utterly! It looks like it should have been a new question as it make my previous answer appear to be off-topic.

Comment: So you want to utilize an **Artificial Neural Network** (ANN) (which is well outside my exerience) This paper may be of some interest: [Prediction of Vehicle Reliability using ANN](http://paris.utdallas.edu/IJPE/Vol08/Issue03/pp.321-329%20Hari%20279.10.pdf) I wonder if stackoverflow is really the right place for your questions. perhaps you should looks through the engineering related stackexchange areas

Comment: @used_by_already thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

mean time **TO** failure

It is (or should be) a predictor of equipment reliability. The **TO** in that term indicates it's predictive intent.

> Mean time to failure (MTTF) is the length of time a device or other
>   product is expected to last in operation. MTTF is one of many ways to
>   evaluate the reliability of pieces of hardware or other technology.
>   https://www.techopedia.com/definition/8281/mean-time-to-failure-mttf

e.g.

1. take total hours of operation of same equipment items
2. divided by the number of failures of those items
3. If there is 100 items, all except one operate for 100 hours.
4. One failure happens 50 hours.
5. MTTF = (( 99 items x 100hrs ) + (1 item x 50 hrs)) / 1 failure = 9950 hours

### ----

I believe you have been calculating **MTBF**

mean time **BETWEEN** failures

This measure is based on recorded events.

> Mean time between failure (MTBF) refers to the average amount of time
>   that a device or product functions before failing. This unit of
>   measurement includes only operational time between failures and does
>   not include repair times, assuming the item is repaired and begins
>   functioning again. MTBF figures are often used to project how likely a
>   single unit is to fail within a certain period of time.
>   https://www.techopedia.com/definition/2718/mean-time-between-failures-mtbf

> the MTBF of a component is the sum of the lengths of the operational
>   periods divided by the number of observed failures
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures

In short the data you have in that table is suited to MTBF calculation, in the manner you have been doing it. I'm not sure what the `lambda` reference would be discussing.

Comment: @PankajJha, you might provide some help

Comment: Not yet @used_by_already, but I have updates to make the Q clearer and advanced, should I edit the post.

Comment: Consider creating a new question instead, if the nature of the extra information invalidates any previous answer, then it should be a new question, and acceptance should be based on just the original question. Note an answer only has to help you arrive at a solution to be accepted.